# Rubbersheeting in QGIS

Tags: qgis, rubbersheeting

Is there a rubbersheet tool in QGIS similar to [ArcMap](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/editing-existing-features/about-spatial-adjustment-rubbersheeting.htm)?

Basically, I want the yellow line to move to the red line.

[image]

**I have tried Vector Bender** with a buffer of 0.1m through to 100m and still get a bad result:

Input

[image]

Bend Green to Red

Output

[image]

Comment: Please don't re-ask questions, even if they were first asked many years ago; these are your [Options when question is duplicate of one with no/inadequate/old answers](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4010).